# Multiple flashes synced differently

Tags: flash, sync-speed, triggers, second-curtain

I was wandering if it would be possible to set up 2 flashes on triggers but synced differently. I.e one 1st curtain and one 2nd curtain. A lot of people will be thinking "why?" but this would be really helpful for some of the work I do.

Answer (score 3):

The camera could trigger some external timer (StopShot for example), which could then trigger whatever sequence it wanted, whenever it wanted, with whatever timing you program into it.  But using only the camera, I don't see any way the camera could issue two triggers.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've been racking my brain for ages about this I'm thinking about using 2 triggers. having 1 set up with my camera and the other set up to be triggered via the test flash button which I would have in my hand. Just asking to see if anybody would know of a solution which wouldn't involve a 2nd trigger. I will look into the stopshot idea. Would be very elaborate for event/rave photography. lol